# css only appends to the first panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have wrote a jQuery to change the button colour to red when some one clicks on it. But that is only work with the first panel but its not working for the rest of the panels. In the first set of button it works but not only for everything. This is the jQuery part.

```
function DurationOnClick(element){
    var buttonId = element.id;
    var buttonName = element.name;
    var buttonIds = ["1Hour", "30Min", "1Day" , "1Week", "1Month"];
    var chartType = $('#chartType').val();
    var idValue = $('#IdValue').val();        

    //after user click the option here we are changing the option black to red.
    $(buttonIds).each(function(i, e) {

      $('#'+e+'[name='+buttonName+']').css("color", "");      
    });

    $('#'+buttonId+'[name='+buttonName+']').css("color", "Blue");         `
```

The html code is like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">Memory Consumption Average</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="MemoryConsumption" id="30Min" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">30 mins</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Hour" style="color:Red" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 hour</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Day" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 day</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Week" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 week</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="MemoryConsumption" id="1Month" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 month</button>
                <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">
                    <div class="row text-center" id="chart3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">Load Average</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="LoadAverage" id="30Min" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">30 mins</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="LoadAverage" id="1Hour" style="color:Red" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 hour</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="LoadAverage" id="1Day" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 day</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="LoadAverage" id="1Week" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 week</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="LoadAverage" id="1Month" onclick="return DurationOnClick(this)">1 month</button>
                <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">                        
                    <div class="row text-center" id="chart2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After removing the first panel the colour changing will happen for the next immediate chart but the charts below that one the changing colour is not happening. Any help to figure out the issue will be really appreciated.

Comment: you have duplicate ids.... ID of an element must be unique in a document

Comment: You can't have duplicate `id`'s.

Comment: The id selectot will fetch only the first element with given id

Comment: but the button name will be different right? isnt it work that way.im taking the button name and the id both.in that case the buttons are unique.

Comment: You set the blue color out of the $.each. Maybe, do you need to do that inside?

Comment: @d7k `'#'+buttonId` will select the first element with the id, then when the name attribute selector is evaluated it will filter out the element selected by first selector

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was actually thinking that, but to my surprised it [worked in chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/4hnejjw8/1/). But that doesn't mean it should be done, as it really shouldn't be working and it's doubtful it will work in each browser.

Comment: i got it @Arun the id should be a unique one to do like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code. This will work perfect with your case:-

```
 function DurationOnClick(ref) {

    var buttonName = $(ref).attr("name");

    $("button[name=" + buttonName + "]").each(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "");
    });

    $(ref).css("color", "Blue");
   }
```

Comment: Welcome :)  Happy coding :)

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari Welldone. Can you please comment/explain lines ? Where is the red color ?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained the problem is you have duplicate IDs, the id-selector will select only the first element with the id so your code will always select the first set of elements.

But a more jQuery-ish solution will be use jQuery event handlers along with class(`duration`) to group them like

```js
$('button.duration').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
})
```

```css
.btn.btn-default.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">Memory Consumption Average</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="MemoryConsumption" data-id="30Min">30 mins</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration selected" name="MemoryConsumption" data-id="1Hour">1 hour</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="MemoryConsumption" data-id="1Day">1 day</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="MemoryConsumption" data-id="1Week">1 week</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="MemoryConsumption" data-id="1Month">1 month</button>
        <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">
          <div class="row text-center" id="chart3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:Black">Load Average</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="LoadAverage" data-id="30Min">30 mins</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration selected" name="LoadAverage" data-id="1Hour">1 hour</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="LoadAverage" data-id="1Day">1 day</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="LoadAverage" data-id="1Week">1 week</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs duration" name="LoadAverage" data-id="1Month">1 month</button>
        <div class="container content" style="width: 600px;">
          <div class="row text-center" id="chart2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have duplicate ID in the HTML form. Consider using the first set of IDs only.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated ID. Your code is ok, but you did it wrong.

`id` attribute is considered **unique**.

`class`attribute is considered **multiple**.

You have put several same `id`, **but CSS and JS are looking only for ONE, so they process the first (only) and leave.**

Change `id` to `class`.
Example: **`class="30mins"`** will turn `red`all the "30mins" buttons.

Do it for every group you want to turn red on click.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you cant have numbers as the first character of an ID or class for your css to apply. If you#re applying style to your `30min` `1hour` etc, you should consider renaming them. I'm not sure if this conflicts with JS as well. See this example:

```
<div class="char">char</div>
<div class="char1">char1</div>
<div class="1char">1char</div>
<div class="1111">1111</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4scs9Lp/)**